# How to smooth a time lapse video

Tags: after-effects, time-lapse

I want to improve my video time lapse made by many pictures. How can add an effect like fade in/out on overlapped photos (1000+). I want nice changes of photos like in this video

so the video play smoothly. An example of a my time lapse is here

Comment: the video links are broken

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a smoother timelapse you should shoot at a higher frequency. If you want you can always blend between two images results in somewhat more smoothenes.
The first video however is made with a totally different technique, there we only have a few videos and use [*morphing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing) to get from one image to the next.

This technique interpolates the colours on one hand, but also the position of different points on the image on the other hand. This requires you to find some keypoints on both images in order to find a corresponding function. There are softwares that can do this for you, but I do not know any I could recommend.

Comment: What is exactly blending and how do I use this?? Can you post a link of this??

Comment: Blending is the generic transition from one image to another.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending

Comment: Yes I was thinking about this.. This is what I meant with "fade in-out" . I used this on movie maker but I don't know how to use it on after effects on multiple pictures.

Answer (score 0):

In the DiCaprio video above, the main technique used is actually morphing.  You could use this to smooth out your time lapse videos, and I believe there is still cheap/ free morphing software available, but the process would be somewhat laborious for the video you posted above.

A better solution would be to use the built-in motion stabilization tools of programs like adobe after effects or final cut pro x. Both of these programs are capable of optical flow analysis and can use it both to re-time motion (and create new in-between frames) and to stabilize footage.

Comment: Yes I want to re-time the motion. But warp stabilisation is risky because it may shake the video. Is there any other tool that smooth the video like warp stabilisation to create new frames between photos?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to find more information about **Frame Blending** or **Motion interpolation**.

This is for example used in timelapse videos to smooth the render.

- To *blend frames*, use ffmpeg with the tblend filter.
  For example the following command can help :
  `ffmpeg -i {input} -vf "tblend=average,framestep=2,setpts=0.50*PTS" -r {srcfps} -{encoding parameters} {output}`. Replace `{input}` by your input file, `{output}` by the name of the output file, `{srcfps}` by your source frames per second, and `-{encoding parameters}` the parameters you tell ffmpeg to output.
  You could also add `minterpolate` filter to the filter stack to add some motion blur.
- To *generate new frames* based on motion, the Butterflow project can help : https://github.com/dthpham/butterflow

  > **Features**
  >
  > Makes **motion interpolated videos** (increase a video's frame rate by rendering intermediate frames based on motion, uses a combination of pixel-warping and blending).
  >
  > Makes **smooth motion videos** (simple blending between frames).
  >
  > Leverages interpolated frames to make **fluid slow motion videos**.

Comment: I'm using `lighten` instead of `average` and it doesn't seem to be working - I've got a timestamp in the footage and instead of blurring together like a lighten-only filter would do it's crisply jumping ahead by 7 seconds each frame.

Comment: Oh... I just reread the documentation on lighten.. I had assumed that if I increased framestep it would blend more frames together but it seems it only blends two.. How do I blend more, say 100 frames at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Please check another way to mix frame using multiple lighten blending.
[image: Blending Time lapse]
https://www.visionrouge.net/web/2020/01/how-to-de-flicker-long-term-time-lapse-pictures-for-smooth-video/

Comment: Welcome! Can you summarize the contents of the link here? That is strongly encouraged so that people can easily get complete answers here and in case the link becomes unavailable in the future.